# How to "return" an error message from a C# property setter to the user?

Tags: c#, validation, properties, user-input

I have a windows form that allows the user to input an integer value. This value is used to update a member of a separate class (foo) so long as it falls within a certain valid range. If the user inputs something invalid, I want an error message to tell the user that the default value for the parameter will be used.

In order to accomplish this, I have been error checking the user input within the code for the windows form before letting foo set the field in question, and simply displaying a message if the input fails the check.

But what I would like to do is send the raw user input to a property setter within the class foo and have the property setter handle all the error checking. For other functions in foo that may require a message be displayed on the user interface, I am simply returning a string, but to my knowledge there is no way to return any sort of status or value from a property setter. Is there a graceful way to bubble up a status message of some sort from a property setter to a different function? I don't want foo to modify the user interface directly.

Thanks in advance for any help or tips, and I apologize if my question is too vague or should be asked differently as I am new to StackOverflow

Comment: You might be interested in [INotifyDataErrorInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Forgive me, I am very new to C# - would this be a way of allowing me to raise an event that could be caught by the windows form in some way?

Comment: Yes, you implment the interface and you can use that to provide information about which properties have errors. Google tutorials about it to learn how to implment it, it is integrated with both WinForms and WPF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem (as well as removed the need to return strings from nearly all my functions) by implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in my class foo and raising a PropertyChanged event to be caught by the windows form whenever it was necessary to let the user know something had changed.

in class foo-

```
public class foo : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public int bar;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string type) {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(type));
        }
    }

    private void test(){
        bar = 1;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("changed int");
    }

}
```

in the windows form:

```
public partial class GUI : Form {
     foo fooinstance = new foo();

     public GUI(){
           InitializeComponent();
           fooinstance.PropertyChanged += doEvent;
     }

     private void doEvent(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e){
        foo updated = sender as foo;
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(e.PropertyName, "changed int")) {
            ShowWhatChanged(updated.bar); //show on GUI
        }
     }
```

}

EDIT:
A more graceful and cleaner way that I ended up using was to utilize callbacks. The GUI passed a function pointer into foo upon instantiation and foo used it as a delegate to pass strings back to the GUI whenever necessary. No events required:

```
public class foo {

    public delegate void UpdateCallback(string msg);
    private UpdateCallback _ucb;
    public foo(UpdateCallback cb){
        _ucb = cb;
    }

    private void test(){
        if(_ucb != null) {
           _ucb("Message Here");
        }
    }
}

public partial class GUI : Form {

     public GUI(){
           InitializeComponent();
           foo fooinstance = new foo(showmessage);

     }

     private void showmessage(string msg){
           //do whatever with the message
     }
}
```